# Flow-type does not retain generic function parameter when returning function

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In my code, I want to return a high order function and flow my argument type to the returning function. The minimal reduced code looks like below.

```
function curry<A, B: A>(a: A): (b: B) => void {
  return () => {}
}

curry(123)("123") // expected error but not
```

I wonder why `B` does not flow to the returning function. It seems like the returning function has the type `(b: any) => void`.

I know in this example I can change the type bound to a signature like `(a: A) => (b: A) => void`. But my real scenario is more complicated and needs a phantom type as a bound, which looks like the `B` above.

So the question is, what type is `B` instantiated to? Can I make a type parameter flow to the argument position of the returning function? Can the type in argument position influence the type inference of an actual argument?

Answer (score 4):

The returned function has type `(b: string) => void` as you can see running the `type-at-pos` command

```
// @flow

function curry<A, B: A>(a: A): (b: B) => void {
  return () => {}
}

const f = curry(123)
f("123")
```

running `flow type-at-pos index.js 7 7` you get:

```
(b: string) => void
```

Keep in mind that, due to how type inference works, the type `A` (and thus `B`) will change accordingly to the following calls

```
const f = curry(123) // <= f now has type (b: string | boolean) => void
f("123")
f(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question. But I still wonder why `void` is inferred because `void` is not a subtype of `number`. And could you please elaborate `how type inference works`? I don't know where I can find good reference for such cases.